# Refer a friend functionality for a website in OOP

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to get to grips with OOP, and just want a little advice on how to approach a problem.

I am making a refer a friend system on my online shop, so when a user registers they will enter an email address of a friend that referred them. This already existing friend then gets a certain amount of points (currency) in their online account.

I have made most of my system just using functions and procedural programming in PHP, but was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to making the refer a friend system in OOP, or even if it is worth building in OOP?

I do understand the basic principles of OOP, but not quite sure how to fully build a program from start to finish using it.

Comment: SO is mostly for code-level questions. For design questions, try [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). However, this question is rather vague and open ended, and not well suited (in its present form) for either. Multiple focused questions would do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is what I would do

```
Class User {
    // ....

    public function newUser(array $params, $isRefer = false, $referal = null) {
             // $params Parameters for new user, like name, address etc
             // $isRefer boolean value to trigger referal
             // $referal Email of the referer
        $newUser = new user_model($params); 
             //Create a DBO of user, as per the new parameters
        if(isReferal) { $referer = $this -> getUserIdByEmail($referal); } 
            //If is referal, get his id, based on email
        $status = $this -> add($newUser); //Add the user
            //Add the user
        if($status) {
             //Once it is success
             $referer = new User($referer); //Create a object of referer
             $referer -> addPoints(50); // Give bonus point

        }
        return true; //Indicate the success
    }

    public function __construct($id = null) {
        if($id) {
           //create the object
           $this -> id = $id;
        }
        // ....
    }

    protected function getUserIdByEmail($email) {
        //get the id
        return $id;
    }

    protected function addPoints($points) {
        //add the points on database table
        return true;
    }
}
```

The DBO class might be something similar to this

```
class UserDBO {
   protected $name;
   protected $address;

   public function __construct(array $params) {
      $this -> name = $params['name'];
      $this -> address = $params['address'];
   }

}
```

---

Usage:

```
$userObj = new User();
$userObj -> newUser(array("name", address"), true, "referal@email.com");
```

Comment: Ok brilliant thanks :) . I wasnt expecting a full blown code example but really appreciate it. I wasnt too sure if it would be worth programming it in OOP because its a relatively small piece of functionallity, but I guess it doesnt look too complicated.

Comment: @JamesG, Yeah good luck. If you hit a bump, you know where to find us ;)